# Part of speech in a sentence

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech, functions

In the sentence:

> "
>   *I let him take the pen*

... are the mentioned functions correct?

*I* = subject
*let* = main verb
*him* = indirect Object
*take* = the second verb (bare infinitive)
*the pen* = Direct Object

Of particular interest is whether *him* is a subject of *take* or an object of *let*. Also what is the function of the infinitival clause "*... take the pen*"?

Comment: You have assigned functions to the words; parts of speech are noun, verb, adjective etc. "Him" is direct (not indirect) object of "let".

Comment: Adding to what Bill says, please take such questions to our chat in the future, for which you have sufficient reputation. This question is way too localized for the main site. This particular sentence is of no interest to a wider audience, and indeed will be very soon of no interest even to yourself. And that's precisely why we have chat in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Actually Reg, this question is one of considerable interest to synracticians. Lots of verbs that end up in sentences looking very similar actually have very different behaviours.. NPs that come directly after the verb are difficult to analyse in terms of whether they are subjects of subordinate clauses or direct objects of matrix clauses. Chomsky and Postal had what was described at the time  as  a "monumental battle" over this very issue.

Comment: @BillJ Is it though? It cannot become the subject of a passive, for example. It doesn't seem to pattern like *make* although it looks the same at first glance ....

Comment: @Araucaria: +1 Thanks for the edition and also your comment. But what is the answer of my question please? I need an answer to help me understand the functions and also perts of speech.

Comment: Hold on, the question has been edited to reflect a different aspect of grammar!

Comment: @Araucaria. I think so. Intervening NPs with infinitivals are always matrix objects. And "let" doesn't passivise with infinitival complements. "Him" is raised object, of course, but that's a matter of semantics.

Comment: Thanks guys. Apparently there is no answer to my question :( I'm a non-native speaker. Whereas you native guys don't offer an answer for such a question, how could I be able to hope to learn English grammar completely? :(

Comment: @franky Your example is analysed like this: "I" = subject/noun; "let" = predicator/verb; "him" = direct object/noun. In the subordinate clause: "take"=predicator/verb; "the pen" = direct object/noun phrase. Note that 'subject, 'predicator' and 'object' are functions. 'Noun' and 'verb' are parts of speech.